# How can I change the application name(space) in Laravel 6

Tags: php, namespaces, laravel-artisan, laravel-6

In previous versions you could use the artisan command

```
php artisan app:name NewName
```

to use change the applications namespace (defaults to App). The artisan command seems to be missing now. Is changing the namespace no longer supported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, the command has been officially removed from Laravel version 6 (see pull request: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/27575).

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/29810

Answer (score 5):

The `app:name` command was removed in Laravel 6, in [this commit](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/fe06c206fcac081d3c93ee7d38eb3174e83603f5#diff-52ce501efc27d62b35ed72232484863b).

You can install [this package](https://github.com/andrey-helldar/laravel-app) to do the job

```
composer require andrey-helldar/laravel-app
```

Answer (score 0):

You should now use [this package](https://github.com/TheDragonCode/laravel-app) to do the job using:

```
composer require dragon-code/laravel-app --dev
```